# Django Posts not showing on live server

Tags: html, django

I made a small blog site and is not showing all the items from the database. If i try to see the posts from my phone i see only 3 posts, when in my DB there are 9. When i click on one post i got a Not Found error saying that the requested URL posts/legea etc was not found on server.

LE: My server is inside a VM. Is this maybe an issue?
This is the link that should have all of the posts: http://cohen.ro/posts/

PS I dont have a migrations folder. I just created now and put an init.py file in it. Bu still after running migrate didn't see the migrations and the result is the same.
However, if i enter in admin trhourgh site/admin i can see all of the posts in DB and when i go back to the site all of the items are out there and i can read the posts.

Can someone, please help me in order to fix this?! thank you!

My post List:

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block head_title %} Blog | {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid" style="width:91%;color: currentColor;!important;">

<div class="row" id="list_posts" style="background-color: white;padding-top: 40px;">
<br/>
<br/>
    <br>
   {% for obj in object_list %}
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        {% if obj.image %}
        <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}"/>
        {% endif %}

      <div class="caption" style="color:currentColor">
          {% if obj.draft %} <h3>Staff Only Draft</h3> {% endif %}{% if obj.publish > today %}<h3>Staff Only: Future Post{%endif%}</h3>
        <h2><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}' >{{obj.title }}</a>  </h2>
          <h5>{{obj.location }} </h5>
          {% if obj.user.get_full_name %}<p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}</p>{% endif %}
        <p>  {{ obj.content |linebreaks |truncatechars:150}}</p>
{#        <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>#}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

{#    {% cycle "" ""  "<div class='col-sm-12'><hr/></div></div><div class='row'style='background-color:white;color:currentColor'>" %}#}
      {% cycle "" ""  "<div class='col-sm-12'><hr/><br/></div><div class='row'style='background-color:white;color:currentColor'></div>" %}

    {% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if object_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ object_list.number }} of {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if object_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ object_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Post Form:

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block head_title %} Blog | {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid" id="post_form_id" style="background-color: teal">

    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
         <h1> Form </h1>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form |crispy }}

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="Create Post">

        </form>
</div>
</div>

{% include 'navbar_bottom.html' %}
{%  endblock %}
```

My Post detail:

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block head_title %} Blog | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid" id="detail_posts" style="background-color: white">
<div class="col-xs-12 offset-xs-0 col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
     {% if instance.image %}
        <img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" />
    {% endif %}
    <h1> {{ title }} <small> {% if instance.draft %} <span style="color:red">{% trans "Draft" %}</span> {% endif %}</small></h1>
{% if instance.user.get_full_name %}
<p> {% trans "Autor:" %} {{ instance.user.get_full_name }}</p>
{% endif %}
    {{ instance.location |linebreaks }} <br/>

    {{ instance.content |linebreaks }} <br/>


<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">Facebook</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status={{ share_string }}%20{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">Twitter</a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}/&title={{ instance.title }}&source={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
Linkedin </a>
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit?url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}/&title={{ instance.title }}">Reddit</a>
 <a href='https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}'>GooglePlus</a>
</div>
</div>

{% include 'navbar_bottom.html' %}
{%  endblock content%}
```

My views:

```
from contact.forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from contact.forms import ContactForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import requests
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def board(request):
    return render(request, 'board.html')

def persoanefizice(request):
    return render(request, 'persoanefizice.html')

def consultanta(request):
     return render(request, 'consultanta.html')

def cyberintelligence(request):
     return render(request, 'cyberintelligence.html')


#
# def pay(request):
#     return render(request, 'pay.html')
def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'blog.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['numele_dumneavoastra']
            contact_phone = form.cleaned_data['numarul_de_telefon']
            # contact_period = form.cleaned_data['perioada_cand_va_putem_contacta']
            subject = contact_name + " | " + contact_phone

            content = form.cleaned_data['mesajul_dumneavoastra']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['emailul_dumneavoastra']

            ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            data = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
            result = r.json()
            ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

            if result['success']:
                try:
                    send_mail(subject,content,contact_email, ['greatjobdone770@gmail.com'])
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')


                return redirect('success')
        else:
            form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Succes! Multumim pt mesajul trimis.')
```

Comment: Can you share your views.py?

Comment: I've uploaded the views. thank you! Please note that i deleted the DB and recreated it and still i have the same error on my phone.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your problem is. Is there anything wrong with your templates? Where is the queryset that's missing blog entries?
Please post only the code needed to reproduce the problem. [mcve]

Comment: hi pls check to see the issue www.cohen/posts/ and click on one post